# Sympy definite integral

Tags: python, sympy, integral

I want to integrate the equation:

> f(x) = integral(E^(-i * omega * t)), from `-a` to `a`.

I wrote the following code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import a, omega, t

init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)


f = E**(-I * omega * t)    

integrate(f, (omega, -a, a))
```

But the result is just the entered definite integral. When I change the integrally limits to `0` to a `I` get a result... Does anyone know how to get a solution from `-a` to `a`?

Many thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sympy does not know about all the things you assume about your variables, so you need to tell sympy explicitly. For example `a` is supposed to be a positive (and hence real) number. If I tell this to sympy, then I get a nice answer. Try

```
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
```

right before

```
integrate(f, (omega, -a, a))
```

And make sure you use a sufficiently recent version of sympy. 1.0 works for me.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!